What is the point of a single 2.5Gbps port on Deco XE75 Pro access points when you have to connect anything else to a 1Gbps port?
Deco XE75 Pro access points only have one 2.5Gbps Ethernet port and two 1Gbps ports (per unit). Do I have to buy a switch to make any use of the faster port? The rest of my wired network is ready for 2.5, and I want the Deco mesh setup with wired backhaul, but... I just don't get what they were thinking for ideal topology.

re: "Deco mesh setup with wired backhaul" "Mesh" took off as a colloquial term for any case when multiple APs broadcast the same network, but the technical term for that feature is "roaming". Meshing is specifically roaming with a wireless backhaul.

How many do you intend to use, and what traffic patterns to you expect (Wireless-Internet, Wireless-Wireless same AP, Wireless-Wireless different APs, Wireless-Wired...)?

These Deco units can get up to about 1.8 Gb/s on the 2.5 Gb's interface (if that is used for the back-haul) with Wifi traffic alone (using multiple Wifi6 clients with good signal strenght).
This is from some quick and dirty measurements that I made myself a few weeks ago on a friends setup. (He was doubting it was really that fast, so we measured.)
Add in 2 wired clients connected to the 1 Gb/s ports and the 2.5 Gb/s is actually starting to look a little under dimensioned...
So yes: Ideally you should use a 2.5 Gbs (of faster) network for the back-haul if you want maximum performance out of these.

Most high-end wireless APs and routers provide a higher bandwidth uplink/backhaul port these days. The general idea is simple, the common case for a majority of users will be that most of the time they need to talk to something outside of the local network (or beyond that router/AP if you’re using a roaming/mesh setup), and as such bandwidth and latency contention will usually be highest on the uplink or backhaul. Thus, using a higher bandwidth and lower latency link for that connection will improve the overall QoS for the whole network.
Given this, if you’re running a wired backhaul anyway, use the 2.5 GbE port for that on each device (and yes, this means you probably need a switch somewhere if you don’t have some kind of base node with more 2.5 GbE ports, and that you probably want Cat6 or better cabling if you’re getting anywhere near the 100m limit). If instead you’re using a wireless backhaul, put whatever needs the lowest latency on the 2.5 GbE port (this will minimize the latency between that device and the AP), and don’t worry about trying to make everything 2.5 GbE unless your devices need to talk to each other very fast (because you will hit bandwidth/latency limits on the wireless backhaul anyway).

Yes, unless you are directly connecting it to a router port with 2.5Gbps interface you will likely need a switch to take advantage of 2.5Gbps - assuming that the device can really push the kind of throughput it claims.
